# Should I pass props as arguments to functions within components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

When I write a function - a helper function for example - inside a component and want to use the value of one of the component's props within this function, should I pass the prop as an argument to the function or access it directly? What might affect this decision? I've always passed the props as arguments but am not sure if this is introducing needless complexity.

I.e. which of the following is best:

```js
function MyComponent({number}){
    function numberPlusOne(){
        return number + 1;
    }

    return(
        <h1>{numberPlusOne()}</h1>
    )
}
```

or

```js
function MyComponent({number}){
    function numberPlusOne(number){
        return number + 1;
    }

    return(
        <h1>{numberPlusOne(number)}</h1>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I did mean ```<h1>{numberPlusOne(number)}</h1>```. Edited to reflect that.

Comment: For small functions like this, they are both same in terms of performance. I prefer the second option if the function can be more "independent", and then you move the function out of Component body. This way you don't have to re-declare the function on re-render, but again, for small functions like this, the effect on performance is negligible.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid re-declaring the function on re-render? Is it computationally expensive to repeatedly declare functions (to an extent that would be noticeable)?

Answer (score 2):

In a functional component, your props are guaranteed to be up-to-date in each render, so I think calling the function with the prop is not more "correct" than using the prop directly inside the function, in terms of the value's correctness and performance.

There are a couple of things to consider though:

- If you use the prop directly inside the function, it makes it more tightly coupled with your component, making it hard to separate it later. But, if it shouldn't be tightly coupled, it should be defined elsewhere in the first place, so...
- If you use the function with the argument, you'd better rename the parameter to prevent [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing), so it's an unnecessary complexity added.

So, all in all, I think it's totally okay to use the prop directly (and recommended) and if you want to make the function reusable by passing the props as arguments, define it elsewhere in the first place (in `utils/` folder, for example).

Comment: So as a general rule of thumb, if the function is directly related to the component (i.e. doesn't have use outside of the context of that component) then use the prop directly. Otherwise lift the function up and store it elsewhere?

Comment: Yeah, that's my suggestion. There's no "official" rule that says so but I'd say that's a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to pass the prop as an argument to the function. Then, you could pull the function up and out of the component and even into a separate file. This also sets you up nicely for unit testing.

Learn more by reading up on "pure functions".